# Removing Spaces of jq command output when reading values from json file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, jq

Working on Azure DevOps pipeline to generate performance reports of the user provided url's (parameter value while they trigger pipeline - inputs urls) using google page speed API, saving the output to json file and using jq to get the values from the json file and saving it to a CSV file. Below is my setup in yml file.

```
- task: Bash@3
  condition: eq('${{ parameters.TestOnMobileDevice }}', true)

  displayName: WebPage_API

  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'

    script: |
      touch web-URL.csv
      chmod 660 web-URL.csv

      echo "
      Website URL,Time Stamp,Mobile Overall Score,Desktop Overall Score" > web-URL.csv

      IFS=' ' read -r -a url <<< "${{ parameters.webPages }}"
      #echo "${url[0]}"
      for webPages in "${url[@]}"
      do

           curl -s "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url={$webPages}&key=*****" -o web.json

           curl -s "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url={$webPages}&strategy=mobile&key=******" -o mobile.json

           printf "\n"
           MobileOverallScore=$(jq .lighthouseResult.categories.performance.score mobile.json)

           DesktopOverallScore=$(jq .lighthouseResult.categories.performance.score web.json)

            echo "

           "$webPages","$(TimeStamp)","$MobileOverallScore","$DesktopOverallScore"" >> web-URL.csv

       done
```

Everything is working fine, but for example the output of

"jq .lighthouseResult.categories.performance.score web.json" is "2.8  s" and when I see the same value in CSV, I see a special character due the space in between 2.8 and s.

[image: CSV]

How do I publish the value to csv without any spaces ??

Answer (score 0):

If `.lighthouseResult.categories.performance.score` does indeed contain a single space, then you could remove it by using this jq program:

```
.lighthouseResult.categories.performance.score | sub(" ";"")
```

To remove all spaces, change `sub` to `gsub`.

One wonders, though, where does the "special character" come from?  To remove unwanted characters, you might wish to consider a filter such as:

```
 gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9.]";"")
```

Comment: Hi, Am trying to get the output from an json file, I have tried this way ,                                    jq .lighthouseResult.audits.interactive.displayValue web.json | sub(" ";"")  I get syntax error and sub command not found

Comment: Your invocation of jq is all wrong. The form should be: `jq 'PROGRAM' web.json`

Comment: am using curl and saving the output to web.Json file and using jq and the command above am extracting the required value from web.json and am getting the result I need, can you tell me what exactly am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Already did. Use single quotes, and put the quoted command before web.json